# ¿En qué parte del código se debe definir y ejecutar la conexión a mongoDB a través de mongoose?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

tengo la siguiente clase que se ejecuta al iniciar la aplicación

**aplicacion.ts:**

```
//==============================================================================================
//======imports de node_modules==================================================================
import * as express from 'express';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as favicon from 'serve-favicon';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import * as stylus from 'stylus';
//import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser'; //cargar el body Parser de forma antigua

//======imports Mis Clases ===============================================================
import { Servidor } from './servidor';
import { Logger } from './AdminLogs/Logger';
import { StartBD } from './BD-Conexiones/StartBD';
import { StartRutas } from './routes/StartRutas';
import { ErrorHandlers } from './ErrorHandlers/ErrorHandler';
//==============================================================================================
export class Aplicacion {

    static app: express.Application; 

    constructor() {

        Aplicacion.app = express();

        //=====================================================================================
        // Cargar el modulo bodyparser ya integrado en express (nueva forma):
        Aplicacion.app.use(express.json());
        Aplicacion.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

        // Cargar el modulo bodyparser no integrado en express (antigua forma):
        // this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
        // this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 

        //Cargar el modulo para el manejo de cookies
        Aplicacion.app.use(cookieParser());
        //======================================================================
        //carga el loggers de morgan y wiston si existen
        Aplicacion.app.use(Logger.configurarLoggerMorgan());
        //=====================================================================================        
        //cargar procesamiento de vistas, estilos y directorio public:                   
        Aplicacion.app.use(stylus.middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));       
        Aplicacion.app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
        Aplicacion.app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
        Aplicacion.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
        // descomentar despues de colocar un favicon en el directorio public
        //this.app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));            
        //=====================================================================================
        //Configurar Cors (Cors se usa para poder comunicar 2 o mas servidores
        Aplicacion.app.use(cors());
        //=====================================================================================
        //Cargar middleware de Conexiones a la BD
        Aplicacion.app.use(StartBD.conectarMongoDB());
        //======================================================================
        //Cargar rutas
        Aplicacion.app.use("/", StartRutas.iniciarRutas());
        //======================================================================
        //Cargar manejadores de errores personalizados
        Aplicacion.app.use(ErrorHandlers.procesarError());
        //====================================================================================
        //Iniciar servidor
        let servidor = new Servidor(Aplicacion.app);
        servidor.iniciarServidor();
        //====================================================================================
    }
}

//==============================================================================================
//entrada de aplicacion (primera ejecucion)
const mainAplicacion = new Aplicacion();
//==============================================================================================
```

**StartBD.ts**

```
//==============================================================================================
//======imports de node_module==========
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {Request, Response, NextFunction, RequestHandler} from 'express';

//======imports Mis clases======
import { _credenciales } from '../../_config/_credenciales';
import { Logger, IWLog } from '../../AdminLogs/Logger';
import { ErrorMongoMongoose, ETipoMongoM } from '../../ErrorHandlers/ErrorsApi';

//==============================================================================================
//==============================================================================================

export class StartBD {

    private static _BDUsuario = _credenciales.BD.config.User;
    private static _BDContrasenna = _credenciales.BD.config.Pass;
    private static _BDNombre = _credenciales.BD.config.BDName;
    private static _StrConexion:string = "mongodb://" + BDMongoMongoose._BDUsuario + ":" + BDMongoMongoose._BDContrasenna + "@cluster0-shard-00-00-vtfgz.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-vtfgz.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-vtfgz.mongodb.net:27017/" + BDMongoMongoose._BDNombre + "?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin";    
    public static isConectado = false; //no implementada    

    constructor() {}

    //========================================================================================
    //conecta a traves de middleware       
    static conectarMongoDB():RequestHandler{

        return function (req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) {                              
            //======================================================================
            //establecer conexion
            //--falta codigo para evitar reconexion----
            mongoose.connect(BDMongoMongoose._StrConexion)
            .then(
                function () {
                    //=======================================
                    //Crear Log de Reporte                        
                    Logger.getLoggerWinston().info(<IWLog>{
                        fecha: new Date(),
                        origen : "BD",
                        detalles: "Conectado a MONGO DB",
                    });
                    //=======================================
                    return next();
                },
                function (err) {
                    err.message = err.message.replace(BDMongoMongoose._BDUsuario, "*******");
                    err.message = err.message.replace(BDMongoMongoose._BDContrasenna, "*******");                      

                    let errPer; 
                    errPer = new ErrorMongoMongoose(ETipoMongoM.errorConexion, null, err);    
                    return next(errPer);
                });                
            //======================================================================
        };
    }
}
```

Me gustaría saber si es correcto el definir la conexión a la base de datos en un archivo externo y si se debe ejecutar la conexión a través de un middleware o por fuera del middleware.

```
        Aplicacion.app.use(StartBD.conectarMongoDB());
```

Ya que si bien el código –como está- realiza la conexión correctamente cuando se envía una petición, pero parece ser que se realizan reconexiones en cada petición, no sé si a futuro esto genere algún inconveniente.

También quisiera saber si ¿es correcto iniciar el servidor en la parte final del  constructor de la clase después de todos los middleware?, gracias.

Comment: Cual es el código de `StartDb`?

Comment: Lo siento se me olvido ingresar el código de StartBD, ya esta actualizado

Comment: Usalo como dice la doc. De la forma que lo usas te creará una conexión por request lo que posiblemente haga fallar a tu servidor

Comment: el código lo obtuve de un tutorial el cual decía que se ejecutaba desde un middleware para evitar que la conexion a mongoBD siempre estuviera abierta,   y como aun no me queda claro como se debe cerrar la conexion a mongoDB o cuando se debe hacer, por ahora seguiré tu consejo, lo quito del middleware y lo ejecuto aparte a ver como funciona, gracias.

Comment: si pero el punto es que la solución al primer problema fue crear otro aún mayor por eso es mejor que lo manejes global a nivel de aplicación

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, lo implemento, lo pruebo y si funciona, cierro la pregunta, de lo contrario comento los inconvenientes que se presenten.